# How to show that vector field is continuous?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

In the book the definition of a a vector field over $U$(open)$ \subseteq S^n$ is given by a continuous map $s: U \to T(U)$ such that $p_U \circ s=id_U$ where $p_U$ is the base point projection from $T(U)$ to $U$.

Now given $v_0\in S^n$ show that there is an open neighbourhood $U \subset S^n$ of $v_0$ and vector fields $s_i:U \to T(U)$, $1 \leq i \leq n$ such that $\{s_1(v),s_2(v),...,s_n(v)\}$ is a basis of the vector space $T_v(S^n)$, $\forall v \in U$.

I approached to extend the basis $v_0$ to an orthonormal basis using Grahm Schmidt normalization process where at each step we have to divide by scalar and subtract all of which are continuous. So I thought this is continuous. Is there any other way to prove continuity using the inverse image of an open set is open?

Comment: Finish the question: such that what ?

Comment: @user152715, edit your question so that we can understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I have finished the definition now.

Comment: Why don't you just choose the vector fields $(s^1,\dots,s^n)$ to be the vector fields $(\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n)$ from a smooth chart $(U,(x^i))$ contain $v_0$ ?

Comment: As this one the problem of first chapter of conlon's book that is why I used only what I had in my hand

Comment: What do we allowed to use ?

Comment: The only definition of continuity and the informations, given in the question